# Interpreting Cluster Heat Maps From R

Tags: data-visualization, clustering

So I have been looking at how to plot high dimensional clustered data, and one of the options that come up is a heat map.

Although there are many webpages that provides code on how to create one, there is very little information about how to interpret a heat map.

So I was wondering how would I interpret the heat map below?

[image: heat map and dendrogram]

Comment: Without any context, and in the absence of all axis labels, how could *anyone* interpret that map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dendrograms along the sides show how the variables and the rows are independently clustered. The heat map shows the data value for each row and column (possibly standardized so they all fit in the same range). Any patterns in the heat map may indicate an association between the rows and the columns. Or you might be able to modify the clustering to create patterns (ordering of leaves within the dendrogram is often arbitrary).

The main pattern to look for is a rectangular area of about the same color. That suggests a group of rows that is correlated for the corresponding group of columns. For instance, the upper fourth of columns 10-13 shows a lot of darker than average values.

Comment: It would help if the heat map's rows were sorted by columns. It would make groups much more visible.